# Jquery Get Class With $get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fix an issue in my code, but having I'm able to get the all of the divs with the class name of .class_name_1. I'm trying to change the display style to none.  It's easy to do in $(*.classname*), but doing it with $get seems to take more.

```
 $get(".class_name_1").style = "none";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do that is

```
$(".class_name_1").css("display","none");
```

Also remember that style is a ***set of properties***, not only a value.
In DOM elements you could use `myElement.style.display='none'`